# "For <xxx> sake" - which variant is more common?

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions

There are a lot of variations of this phrase, most notably including

- "for God's sake"
- "for Heaven's sake"
- "for Jesus sake"
- "for Pete's sake"

Which of those are most commonly used in modern English? Is there any context in which one of them should be preferred? For example, I have never *ever* heard about "for Pete's sake" before reading "I, Robot" by Isaac Asimov, where this term is widely used.

Comment: "for Jesus sake" - From my youth, a religious friend would always close a prayer (spoken publicly) with "...for Jesus sake; Amen" - as I recall that is the only time I have heard that particular phrase used, never to express disappointment! However, the other 3 phrases (including "Pete's") are relatively common. (England)

Comment: Here (central Scotland) God and Pete win. Never heard the other two.

Comment: Shouldn't the third option be _"for Jesus' sake"_?  But either way, my vote would (sadly) go for _"for f**k's sake"_, often abbreviated to _"ffs"_ and used very frequently in common language on the internet.

Comment: I've never heard "for Jesus'[s] sake".  "For Christ's sake", pronounced and often spelled "ferchristsake", yes.

Comment: You requested context: in polite company (read: puritan) taking the Lord’s name in vain in any guise is still ill advised.  Albeit Pete is probably standing in for St. Peter, that’s still the best of your choices.  (Also – “For the love of Mike.”, “For crying out loud.”)  My family used, “For Pete Sakes”, and if they really wanted to burn the house down, “For Heaven sakes.” [Yes – both malformed, without the subject plural.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both the COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English) and the BNC (British National Corpus), *for God’s sake* is by far the most frequent. It is followed in the COCA by *for Christ’s sake* and by *for Heaven’s sake* in the BNC, where *for Christ’s sake* ranks third. *For Pete’s sake* comes in at number four in both, and occurrences of *for Jesus’s sake* are negligible.

Comment: How do those compare to *For goodness sake*?

Comment: @Jim: It ranks below ‘for Pete’s sake’ in the COCA, but above it in the BNC. In both, however, it ranks above ‘for fuck’s sake’.

Answer (score 13):

*Google Ngram Viewer* [reports](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+God%27s+sake%2Cfor+heaven%27s+sake%2Cfor+Heaven%27s+sake%2Cfor+Jesus+%27+sake%2Cfor+Jesus+sake%2Cfor+Jesus%27s+sake%2Cfor+Pete%27s+sake%2Cfor+fuck%27s+sake%2Cfor+pete%27s+sake%2Cfor+Petes+sake%2Cfor+petes+sake%2Cfor+goodness+sake&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0) that *for God’s sake* is most popular in their collection of published books, with *for Heaven’s/heaven’s sake* second and *for Jesus’ sake* third:

[image]

Use of all but *for God’s sake* and *for heaven’s sake* tapered off [during the 20th Century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+heaven%27s+sake%2Cfor+Heaven%27s+sake%2Cfor+Jesus+%27+sake%2Cfor+Jesus+sake%2Cfor+Jesus%27s+sake%2Cfor+Pete%27s+sake%2Cfor+fuck%27s+sake%2Cfor+pete%27s+sake%2Cfor+Petes+sake%2Cfor+petes+sake%2Cfor+goodness+sake&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0). At the same time, *for Pete’s sake* and *for fuck’s sake* made an appearance. *Pete* and *fuck* have never caught up to *heaven*, but are giving *Jesus* a good run for His money:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For f***’s sake!

Everyone has their favourite, I am sure there are regional variations, and these expressions come and go in popularity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doric_dialect_(Scotland)

“Fit Like” is a common expression meaning “What are you like?”

http://www.highland-spirit.com/acatalog/Scottish_Greeting_Cards.html

Comment: Just that first sentence would be enough to get my upvote! For the record, I have *never* heard anyone use *"For Jesus sake!"* as an oath here in the UK, and *"For heaven's sake!"* sounds positively pre-war to my ear.

Comment: For f**k's sake is very popular on the internet, and is frequently abbreviated as FFS.